# how to calculate the real probability

Tags: probability

Say I have a 50% probability of winning a game if I play against person 1, and a 50% probability of winning a game against person 2. I will play with both people, one after another. Before the matches, what was the probability that I would win at least 1 match? It has to be something between 90-99% I think. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: How many trials are you doing? Are the trials independent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: as Austin Mohr's helpful follow-up comment explains, the answer relies on the fact that the ***likelihood*** of a win and a loss are the ***same***: we have $50\%$ chance of a win $= 50\%$ chance of a loss in each game, so every outcome is equally likely.

W: win... L: lose

**Four** possible outcomes: (Game 1 vs. person 1) followed by (Game 2 vs. person 2)

`W W <--`

`W L <--`

`L W <--`

`L L`

In $3$ of $4$ outcomes, you win one or both (at least one) of the two games. In only one outcome, will you lose both (and hence **not** win at least once).

Therefore: The probability of winning at least one game: $P(\text{win at least one game}) = \dfrac 34 = 75\%$

Comment: thank you for your help, really appreciate it

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Nice write - up +1

Answer (score 1):

person 1 person 2
win      win
person 1 person 2
win      lose
person 1 person 2
lose     win
person 1 person 2
lose     lose

I see the answer being 75% for winning at least one match.